# Update table field -Error "Operation must use an updatable query" (Ms Access 2013)

Tags: ms-access

I'm kind of a beginner in Access and I think I'm a little out of my depth with this problem

We've been using this access database that includes tables `Finding` and `ActionFinding`. Each has a field [Status] which is a number from 1-3.

I want to update `Finding`.Status to the minimum corresponding ActionFinding.Status

The relationship between Finding and ActionFinding is 1 to many.

I've tried the following code in an update query but am getting the following error

> Operation must use an updatable query

```
UPDATE Finding INNER JOIN ActionFinding 
         ON Finding.[FindingID] = ActionFinding.[FindingID] 
SET Finding.Status = (SELECT MIN([ActionFinding].[Status]) 
  FROM ActionFinding 
  WHERE Finding.[FindingID] = ActionFinding.[FindingID]);
```

I've tried creating a separate query to group the findings and return the minimum, and create a new update query to update the Finding.Status with the grouped one but the grouped query is understandably not an updatable query, so I got the same error.

Since this database has new entries constantly, I can't create a temp table every time a new entry occurs to use the update query. I want automatic or form buttons to update the original Finding table. I've checked similar questions about the error but they all mention permissions and temp tables, which is not the solution that I'm looking for. I've been trying to figure out a solution for hours but hit a dead end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query is not updateable if it includes any aggregate function, even if this function is in separate query. Try to replace aggregate function by `DMin()` function.

Comment: The following code worked perfectly
    
'UPDATE Finding INNER JOIN ActionFinding ON Finding.FindingID = ActionFinding.FindingID SET [Finding].[Status] = DMin("Status","ActionFinding","FindingID="& [Finding].[FindingID]);' 

Thank you for your help, I really appreciate it